# Query regarding fsim verilog versus Zedboard verilog code of Rocket core

Tags: riscv

Could someone help explain what the differences are between the verilog code generated from the fsim directory of the rocket core (Top.DefaultFPGAConfig.v, using the default conf files provided) and the verilog code in the Zedboard folder (Top.DefaultFPGAConfig.v)? They are more or less of the same size, and look similar apart from a few changes which i couldnt quite understand the reason behind..

I am trying to synthesize it on a virtex 7 FPGA and not a Zynq based board, but just wanted help to understand what was different between the two sources for my knowledge.

Also, has anyone synthesized the fsim verilog code and run it with the testbench on an FPGA (non-Zynq based)?

Answer (score 1):

The verilog included in the fpga-zynq repo should be the same as what the same config would produce inside fsim within rocket-chip because that is how it was generated. It is possible that if you use a newer version of chisel or rocket-chip to regenerate the verilog, you will get slightly different verilog. This is just a case of not committing to fpga-zynq as often as chisel itself is updated. Some of the updates to chisel tweak its internal passes, so it sometimes results in slightly different verilog output.

We have not tested the verilog on non-Zynq FPGAs. The verilog itself isn't that specialized, so I would expect most of the pain for getting it onto a Virtex 7 would be interfacing with it. I would definitely take a look at rocketchip_wrapper.v to get a feel for the external connections rocket-chip expects.

Comment: "most of the pain for getting it onto a Virtex 7 would be interfacing with it".  I believe the current riscv-tools are relying on the existence of an ARM core on the FPGA to facilitate communication between the user's host machine (laptop) to the Rocket core on the FPGA fabric. I would assume this means that porting to other non-zynq boards would require rewriting some of the riscv-fesvr code ("fesvr-zedboard" is the resulting binary), but maybe I'm wrong about that?

Comment: Yes. Deciding how to wrap the rocket-chip and talk to it remotely via riscv-fesvr is the work I was referring to. The memory interface for rocket-chip is quite simple.